# What does "not foundh" mean from a .sh script?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sh

I'm trying to run a script called `autogen.sh` on my Ubuntu system (WSL) which begins with

```
#!/bin/sh

set -xe

type autoreconf > /dev/null || exit 1
type pkg-config > /dev/null || exit 1
```

You can get the full script by running `git clone https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags.git`

And it gives me

```
mark@surface-19:~/ctags$ ./autogen.sh 
: not foundh: 2: ./autogen.sh: 
./autogen.sh: 3: set: Illegal option -
```

I'm having a hard time understanding the error message "not foundh". It seems to be a typo of "not found"  but what exactly is not being found?